# Expected expression error on a temperature conversion table

Tags: c

Getting an "expected expression error" on line 17 when following the C programming book.  Complete noob here and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
int main()
{
float fahr, celsius;
int lower, upper, step;

lower = 0; /* lower limit of temperature table */
upper = 300; /* upper limit */
step = 20; /*step size */

fahr = lower;
while (fahr <= upper ) {
    celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr - 32.0);
    printf(“%3.0f %6.1f\n”, fahr, celsius);
    fahr = fahr + step;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You copied code from PDF file ??

Comment: No, I borrowed the book from the library.  I'm trying to learn and I'm writing down the code from the book in Xcode as I go along and realizing that I'm making subtle mistakes here and there.

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace the quotes `“”` in

```
printf(“%3.0f %6.1f\n”, fahr, celsius);
```

with standard double quotes `""`

```
printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
```

As an aside, you should also `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of the file for a declaration of `printf`

Comment: How do I avoid this mistake again?  When I was typing I didn't know how to differ between the two different types of quotation marks.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're using a word processor to create your code, try using the editor that comes with an IDE instead.  Or a plain old text editor.  If you're already doing this or can't change editor, try disabling any options about smart quotes.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf(“%3.0f %6.1f\n”, fahr, celsius);
//     ^             ^   Those quotes are not standard
```

Replace those quotes by the standard ones :

```
printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
//     ^             ^
```

The compilers are strict, the `“”` and `""` do not mean the same thing.